# Android design support library для API 28 не работает

Tags: android, android-support-library, manifest

Решил опробовать новые штуки из обновленной support библиотеки. Скачал новую версию студии 3.2. Создаю проект, добавляю элемент в xml. И не работает. Ошибка такая:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha3] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha3] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-23:19 to override.
```

Если же выполнить то, что он просит, то получим так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    package="*****">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

И тогда ошибка вот такая:

```
Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:6 for attribute
android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this
 file), line 5 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)
```

Кто-нибудь уже использовал новый апи? Что я делаю не так? И как это все исправить. Студию ставил на чистую винду, так что совсем не понятно(

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ № 1**
Создал подкласс. Унаследовал его от AppComponentFactory. Дописал указание в манифест: `android:appComponentFactory="android.argument.twins.plykekn.SubAppComponentFactory"`

Получил новую ошибку:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
at org.gr
```

Напоминает ошибку с proguard, но он отключен. Есть еще идеи?)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ № 2**
Пересоздал проект раза три, понял, что делал не так. Теперь проект компилируется, но при попытке запустить приложение падает с ошибкой

```
Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

Продолжу поиск ответов. Как только получиться запустить - приведу ниже алгоритм как новые чудеса matireal design подключить к проекту. Если кто это уже делал, пжлста поделитесь ссылкой на демо репозиторий!

Comment: увы, время для опытов вышло. подожду, когда появиться боле стабильная версия...

Answer (score 2):

возможно проблема в зависимостях, используй либо:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

либо для AndroidX:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
```

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html